# Mouse suddently won't work in current document

Tags: mouse

I'm working in Microsoft word.  I must have hit something wrong as now my mouse pointer doesn't show up on the document.  It does show up on the bottom tool bar and works fine with other documents and programs. I don't want to lose the document I've created. Any one know how to correct this with the original document?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> will save. Then restart Word. (This might not work if no-mouse is some type of feature).